# font-size type of an argument of a Styled-Component

Tags: css, typescript, types, styled-components

How can I specify that the passed argument is of type `font-size` in `Styled-Component`?

Here is my code in TypeScript:

```js
export const StyledOldPrice = styled.span<{ fontSize: <HERE> }>`
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: ${({ fontSize }) => (fontSize ? fontSize : "smaller")};
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  color: #656b6f;
`;
```

To get the IntelliSense when using the style, e.g. `larger`, `x-small`, `smaller` ...etc.

```js
<StyledOldPrice fontSize={...} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "[string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types)"

```
export const StyledOldPrice = styled.span<{
  fontSize: "smaller" | "larger" | "x-small";
}>`
```

**Update**

In order `fontSize` type to be the same as html element `fontSize`, there are 2 options:

1. Import it from `csstype` (This is what jsx uses)

```
import type {StandardLonghandProperties} from 'csstype';

export const StyledOldPrice = styled.span<{
  fontSize: StandardLonghandProperties["fontSize"];
}>`
```

**+**: It will accept any value the "regular" `fontSize` accepts (e.g. '20px', 20, 'smaller' etc.)

**-:** There will be no autocomplete because `fontSize` can basically be any `string` or `number`.

**A note:** Ideally, we could take only the string literals from the union and remove `string`, something like this `Exclude<StandardLonghandProperties["fontSize"], string>` but unfortunately, currently [it's not possible](https://twitter.com/moshfeu/status/1397520550621327361).

---

2. Copy `fontSize` and `AbsoluteSize` from `csstype` without `string` and `number`.

```
import type { Globals } from 'csstype';
type AbsoluteSize = "large" | "medium" | "small" | "x-large" | "x-small" | "xx-large" | "xx-small" | "xxx-large";
type FontSize = Globals | AbsoluteSize | "larger" | "smaller";

export const StyledOldPrice = styled.span<{
  fontSize: FontSize;
}>`
```

**+**: There will be autocomplete.

**-:** It will accept only the "predefined" values such as `smaller`, `inherit` etc.

https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-violet-1qdmp?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: No other way to detect and grab all defined values?

Comment: First, as far as I tested, I don't get autocomplete even when I type `style` on a regular div. I think it because `fontSize` can also be string or number so you basically can put it any value. But if you want it to be just like every element's `fontSize`, you can use the type `StandardLonghandProperties["fontSize"]` by `import type {StandardLonghandProperties} from 'csstype';`. Still the you won't get autocomplete. If you want autocomplete by limiting the options from the closed list (like `smaller`, `larger`, `inherit` etc), you can `import type {Globals, AbsoluteSize} from 'csstype';`

Comment: And `type FontSize = Globals | AbsoluteSize | "larger" | "smaller"`. I've updated the codesandbox.

Comment: Can you update the answer as well, please?

Comment: I am getting this error while importing `Module '"csstype"' has no exported member 'AbsoluteSize'.ts(2305)`

Comment: You are right :( Seems like you have to copy `AbsoluteSize` as well.

Comment: Does it accept the font in pixels as well? If not how to add pixels support?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232906/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-white159).

Comment: As I mentions, in this case, every string will be valid therefor there will be no autocomplete.

Comment: The reason we can't "extract" only the union literal and skip string from `StandardLonghandProperties["fontSize"]` - https://twitter.com/moshfeu/status/1397520550621327361

Answer (score 0):

Or even a better and simpler approach that accepts all values `font-size` property in `CSS` accepts including strings "px, em, ...etc":

```
import styled from "styled-components";
export type FontSize = Property.FontSize;

export const StyledOldPrice = styled.span<{
  fontSize: FontSize;
}>`
```